# How to store results from for loop into a single line?

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following code with beautifulsoup, wehere I am scraping some text from a hrefs:

```
for z in zz:
    links = z.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        aaa = link.text
```

Printing this would result in:

```
blabla
test
word2
etc
```

And I would like to have them in a single variable like this, after it scrapes all of them:

```
blabla, test, word2, etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you would add the print statement in you example, but I assume in your second loop.

To join all the `link.text`s into a single string you can use

```
myline = ', '.join(link.text for link in links)
```

Comment: No need for second set of parents inside `join` call parens; when a generator expression is the only argument to a function, the function call parens double as the generator expression parens. Also, may as well inline the `z.find_all('a')` call; storing it only to use it a single time isn't gaining anything on readability.

Comment: Ty @Geotob, that solved. And thank you ShadowRanger for explaining !

Comment: True enough @ShadowRanger, didn't spot and will fix. Didn't inline `z.find_all` because I wasn't sure if that was the line Alex was after

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a list, then print the list..

```
print(','.join(link.text for link in z.find_all('a')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options.

**Print as array**

```
'''
Output: [blabla, test, word2, etc]
'''

# From links
print([link.text for link in links])

# From z
print([z.findall('a') for z in zz])
```

**Print strings individually**

```
'''
Output: blabla, test, word2, etc
'''

# From links
print(', '.join(link.text for link in links))

# From z
print(', '.join(z.findall('a') for z in zz))
```